# Скорость загрузки страница (Выполнение скриптов PHP/JS)

Tags: php, javascript, localstorage

Вчера вечером все было отлично, никаких лагов/багов не было. Сегодня утром проснулся, и не могу найти проблему. И так.

Есть у меня слайдер в начале страницы. В админ-панеле я добавил возможность свернуть его. В развернутом виде он выглядит вот так:
[joxi_screenshot_1474553856809.png http://s16.postimg.org/lhkccclhx/joxi_screenshot_1474553856809.png](http://postimg.org/image/3rinrb7wx/)

В свернутом :
[joxi_screenshot_1474553856809 (1).png http://s13.postimg.org/h36fv47hz/joxi_screenshot_1474553856809_1.png](http://postimg.org/image/jx9l8k9o3/)

В шапке сайта я подключаю все что нужно:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= PATH ?>css/admin.css">
    <script src="<?= PATH ?>js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="<?= PATH ?>js/storage.js"></script>
    <script src="<?= PATH ?>js/cookie.js"></script>
    <script src="<?= PATH ?>js/transliteration.js"></script>
    <script src="<?= PATH ?>js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?= PATH ?>js/control_panel.js"></script>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?= PATH ?>image/favicon.png" type="image/png">
```

Сам скрипт выполнения:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var sliderBlock = $('.sliderBlock');
    var hideSlider = $('#hideSlider');
    var storage = $.localStorage;

    if (storage.get('_slider') == 'hide') {
        sliderBlock.css({'height': '50px'});
        hideSlider.css({'transform': 'rotate(-45deg)'})
    }

    hideSlider.click(function () {
        if (storage.get('_slider') == 'show' || !storage.get('_slider')) {
            storage.set('_slider', 'hide');
            sliderBlock.css({'height': '50px'});
            hideSlider.css({'transform': 'rotate(-45deg)'})
        } else {
            storage.set('_slider', 'show');
            hideSlider.css({'transform': 'rotate(0)'});
            sliderBlock.css({'height': '350px'})
        }
    })
}); // Slider SHOW / HIDE functions
```

Я подключил библиотеку `storage.js`, при загрузке страницы она проверяет значение
`storage.get('_slider')`, оно может быть `hide` и `show`. Всегда у меня стояло `hide`.

Вчера еще при загрузке страницы слайдер всегда загружался в свернутом виде, сегодня же, не знаю почему, загружается страница с открытым слайдером, и потом уже слайдер уменьшается до 50 пикселей. Я целый день ломаю голову из за чего это могло произойти.

Может ли это быть из за скорости выполнения PHP скриптов? Какие могут быть причины?

**UPDATE | описание файла `control_panel.js`**

И так, все остальные идут после функции управлением слайдера.

1. Открывает / закрывает окно авторизации. Начинает работу по клику на кнопку
2. Скрывает блок сообщений с ответом на действие который появляется после перезагрузки страницы. Работает только если есть такой ответ от сервера, и по клику скрывает блок
3. AJAX передача данных методом пост, после того как были замечены изменения в разных инпутах, в т. ч. и в слайдере. Текст слайдера - это прозрачные инпуты
4. Открытие и скрытие блоков с информацией. Они только на одной странице, так же работает по клику на кнопку
5. Транслитерация url (с кириллицы на лат. по клику на кнопку).
6. TinyMCE - превращает все  в HTML редактор

Больше нет никаких функций. Только один слайдер всегда работал и работае на всех страницах и сразу при загрузке страницы

Comment: есть ли у Вас другие вызовы `$(document).ready(...` кроме того, что в вопросе?

Comment: Да, есть. Всего их 7 штук, вместе с указаным выше.

Comment: + До вчера подобной проблемы не было.

Comment: "Подробности давай!" - другие `$(document).ready` находятся до или после, что делают? Убирайте их по очереди.

Comment: описал файл с функциями

Comment: По моему все нормально происходит, ваш скрипт ждет загрузки всего, а потом уже выполняется, и вопрос только как долго прогрузится dom и все скрипты. Ну и ждет наверное еще пока слайдер построится, если он не просто одна картинка.

Comment: Ну если логически мыслить то да, согласен. Но! До вчера было совсем по другому, из за чего могло случится подобное ?

Comment: `php` тут точно не причем. И да, действительно все нормально, у вас в соседнем топике видно что слайдер по умолчанию открыт. Логично его по умолчанию скрывать. И не используйте эту "лапшу" в js, достаточно добавлять класс вроде `.active` в `.sliderBlock` и в нем уже все крутить.